# How to duplicate rows in GridLayout

Tags: python, pyqt

Let's assume that I have a grid layout with this 1 row:
Sample grid layout form:
[image: Sample grid layout form]

I would like to duplicate this same row a set amount of times when the app launches (Sometimes it's 4 rows or sometimes it's 12).
Is there a smarter way for me to achieve this other than just having to code the same row in a for loop and inserting it?

Comment: A for loop would be used anyway, no matter what you want to "duplicate", so the actual question is: why do you need to do it in another way (or what makes you think there could be one)?

Comment: Well there might be times where I want to change the contents of a row and it would be easier to go and edit from the designer instead of having to deal with written code. But yes you're right that there would be a for loop no matter what. I just prefer something in the spirit of "addRow(row1)"

Comment: For simple layouts like yours, I wouldn't even care about creating that row in designer, and I'd always create it programmatically, but you could also build that row layout in a separate widget in designer, then add it programmatically as many times as you need. That said, a layout like that seems more like a table, so, why don't you just use a QTableWidget instead?

Comment: Well, this was really just a proof of concept example. The actual row I want to create contains multiple textboxes and buttons!

Comment: Ok, then the only option you have (besides creating each row programmatically) is to create a simple widget in Designer that will be used as a "base form", and add it to the main window as many times you need within your code (again, with a for loop).

Comment: Would the main form contain a gridlayout, and I append the rows to it? Because the problem remains that I need to specify the row and column for each widget that I add to a gridLayout. As of now, I have a gridLayout in the main window which contains just the header. And then in a separate widget in Designer, I have a gridlayout that has a sample row that I'm looking to add to the main window gridlayout. Is this the right approach?

Comment: If you need to keep the "main" grid layout, you cannot, as a designer created form will have its own layout. At this point I'd stick with the for loop and create the rows internally.